# Is it an architecture issues to Use DAO within another DAO and Entity-reference within another Entity?

Tags: java, dao

I am working on java web application with MVC-architecture (JSP+SERVLETS+MYSQL && NO ORM-FRAMEWORKS) and I have next database: [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHYWm.png).

I wanted to create table by JSTL core lib on my JSP-view that looks like that:

| ReceptionID | ServiceName | ReceptionCost | YourMaster | Status | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Haircut | 20 USD | Peter Anderson | New | 17.06.2022 10:00 |

So i decided to make next Entity and DAO architecture:

This is my Entity for ReceptionTable in database.

```
public class Reception extends BaseEntity {
private Service service;
private User master;
private User client;
private int cost;
private LocalDateTime receptionDateTime;
private Status status;
// getters setters
}
```

I am worried about Reception contains another Entities (Service, User) and it makes me to use DAO inside another DAO:

```
public class ReceptionDAO implements GenericDAO<Reception> {

public Reception mapReception(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DaoException {
    Reception reception = new Reception();

    long receptionId = resultSet.getLong("id");
    long serviceId = resultSet.getLong("service_id");
    long masterId = resultSet.getLong("master_id");
    long clientId = resultSet.getLong("client_id");
    int cost = resultSet.getInt("cost");
    LocalDateTime dateTime =resultSet.getTimestamp("reception_date_time").toLocalDateTime();
    int statusId = resultSet.getInt("status_id");

    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    ServiceDAO serviceDAO = new ServiceDAO();

    reception.setId(receptionId);
    reception.setService(serviceDAO.findById(serviceId));
    reception.setMaster(userDAO.findById(masterId));
    reception.setClient(userDAO.findById(clientId));
    reception.setCost(cost);
    reception.setReceptionDateTime(dateTime);
    reception.setStatus(Status.getStatus(statusId));

    return reception;
}
```

So i have a several questions:

1. Is it good practice to use entity-object reference in another entity?
2. Does it make sense to use DAO inside another DAO or maybe it is a bad practice?
3. If it is a very big problem, tell me how can i solve this.

Comment: Why not use joins?

Comment: How can i use joins while not using JPA/Hibernate?